# Infinite loop when db.Ping() is called

Tags: go, pq

I am attempting to create a basic connection to a database. The problem happens when I try to test the connection with `db.Ping()`; everything works until I get to this line. The `Ping` sends the program into an infinite loop (the function call never returns), and I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

```
package main
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
}
type Page struct {
    Name     string
    DBStatus bool
}
const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 8080
    user     = "username"
    password = "password"
    dbname   = "GoTest"
)
func main() {

    templates := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html"))

    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        p := Page{Name: "Gopher"}

        if name := r.FormValue("name"); name != "" {
            p.Name = name
        }

        p.DBStatus = db.Ping() == nil //this point is reached but never returned

        if err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", p); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    })

    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}
```

It seems I can connect to the database fine, as the `sql.Open` call doesn't return an error, and if I called the `Ping` outside of the http server handle function, it also returns just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database configurations are wrong. It's pointing to the Golang server port `8080`. It should point to the pgsql port(default 5432)

Comment: This fixed my issue. A simple oversight on my part, thank you for the response!

Comment: The infinite loop is in fact infinite connections to itself.

Comment: @SeanF, db.Ping does not send a valid HTTP request, so there is no recursion.